# difftool - Only loading 1 version of gitfile instead of 2

Tags: git, compare, atlassian-sourcetree, difftool, git-difftool

I'm trying to use [INET PDFC](https://www.inetsoftware.de/products/pdf-content-comparer) as a difftool for comparing different versions of a pdf file.

**Config file**

```
... 
[diff]
    tool = pdfc
[difftool "pdfc"]
    cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/i-net PDFC/PDFC.exe' $LOCAL $REMOTE
```

When I run `git difftool HEAD HEAD^ <filename>` I only see 1 file.

How can I load the two versions to this tool?
Or should I use the .bat file? And how?

Answer (score 0):

Try `git difftool -t=pdfc HEAD HEAD^ <filename>` to specify the tool.